# $addfields removes the key and value pair from the final result : MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Input:

```
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("62b2beb8bfe272962f274942"),
            "CDF" : {
                "UTILITYTYPE" : {
                    "D1" : {
                        "G1" : "12387835",
                        "G2" : "02-06-2022 13:03:23",
                        "G22" : {
                            "NAME" : "LARSEN AND TOUBRO LIMITED"
                        }
                    },
                    "D5" : {
                        "EVENT" : [
                            {
                                "CODE" : "14",
                                "TIME" : "23-05-2022 09:23:39",
                                "STATUS" : "0",
                                "SNAPSHOT" : [
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-1-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "218.39",
                                        "UNIT" : "V"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-2-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "243.67",
                                        "UNIT" : "V"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-3-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "241.37",
                                        "UNIT" : "V"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P2-1-1-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0.456",
                                        "UNIT" : "A"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P2-1-2-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "A"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P2-1-3-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "A"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P4-1-1-0-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "-0.99",
                                        "UNIT" : "NA"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P4-2-1-0-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "NA"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P4-3-1-0-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "NA"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P7-1-5-2-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "2383.03",
                                        "UNIT" : "k"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "CODE" : "14",
                                "TIME" : "23-05-2022 10:40:49",
                                "STATUS" : "1",
                                "SNAPSHOT" : [
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-1-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "227.58",
                                        "UNIT" : "V"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-2-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "236.78",
                                        "UNIT" : "V"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-3-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "236.78",
                                        "UNIT" : "V"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P2-1-1-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "A"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P2-1-2-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "A"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P2-1-3-1-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "A"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P4-1-1-0-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "NA"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P4-2-1-0-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "NA"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P4-3-1-0-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "0",
                                        "UNIT" : "NA"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "PARAMCODE" : "P7-1-5-2-0",
                                        "VALUE" : "2383.16",
                                        "UNIT" : "k"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Expected output:

```
     {
         "_id" : ObjectId("62b2beb8bfe272962f274942"),
         "CDF" : {
             "UTILITYTYPE" : {
                 "D1" : {
                     "G1" : "12387835",
                     "G2" : "02-06-2022 13:03:23",
                     "G22" : {
                         "NAME" : "LARSEN AND TOUBRO LIMITED"
                     }
                 },
                 "D5" : {
                     "EVENT" : [
                         {
                             CODE:14,
                             TIME :23-05-2022 09:23:39,
                             STATUS: 0,
                             "SNAPSHOT" : [
                                 {
                                     "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-1-1-0",
                                     "VALUE" : "218.39",
                                     "UNIT" : "V"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-2-1-0",
                                     "VALUE" : "243.67",
                                     "UNIT" : "V"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-3-1-0",
                                     "VALUE" : "241.37",
                                     "UNIT" : "V"
                                 }
                             ]
                         },
                         {
                             CODE:14,
                             TIME :23-05-2022 10:40:49,
                             STATUS: 0,
                             "SNAPSHOT" : [
                                 {
                                     "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-1-1-0",
                                     "VALUE" : "227.58",
                                     "UNIT" : "V"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-2-1-0",
                                     "VALUE" : "236.78",
                                     "UNIT" : "V"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "PARAMCODE" : "P1-2-3-1-0",
                                     "VALUE" : "236.78",
                                     "UNIT" : "V"
                                 }
                             ]
                         }
                     ]
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

I am using below $add Fields

```
        {
              "CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D5.EVENT": {
                $map: {
                  input: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D5.EVENT",
                      cond: {
                        $in: [
                          "V",
                          "$$this.SNAPSHOT.UNIT"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  in: {
                    "SNAPSHOT": {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$$this.SNAPSHOT",
                        as: "d",
                        cond: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$d.UNIT",
                            "V"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                } 
         
              }  
              
          }
```

which removes the STAUS , TIME AND CODE from my final result

How can i keep STAUS , TIME AND CODE from my final result?

Comment: If `SNAPSHOT` in the document of `CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D5.EVENT` array returns `[]` (empty array), do you want to remain the `EVENT` document?

Comment: no i dont want to return if the snapshot remains empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `$mergeObjects` (and simplify the query a bit):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D5.EVENT": {
        $map: {
          input: "$CDF.UTILITYTYPE.D5.EVENT",
          as: "event",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$event",
              {
                SNAPSHOT: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$event.SNAPSHOT",
                    as: "d",
                    cond: {$eq: ["$$d.UNIT", "V"]}
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pKAnGZH8zr3)